# Match all routes with or without .html extension, except for static assets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to set up a generic handler for every request that is not something like an image or favicon or anything like that. For example I want this handler to handle `/index`, `/index.html`, `/user/123`, etc., but not `/favicon.ico`, `/sunflower.png`, `/images/starfish.png`, etc.
This is currently what I have

```
app.get('/:name', (req, res) => {
  res.render(req.params.name)
})
```

But this is of course matching `/favicon.ico`, and every other url that I don't want it to match. It also doesn't match `.html` extensions. Is there a clean solution out there for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in a production environment to serve static assets, like the images you have listed, is to place a front facing proxy (eg: nginx) in front of Express and configure it accordingly.

That way, request for static assets are offloaded to the proxy, and never reach Express. Express is best for serving dynamic content asynchronously, do not use it for serving files.